# Switch Event Being Skipped in Debug

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which has random chances of random events occurring. I have a switch statement like so which switches a random number:

```
(property)

  static Random RandomObject { get; set; } = new Random();

  ...

  RandomObject = new Random();
                switch (RandomObject.Next())
                {
                    case 1 when RandomObject.Next(1, 3) == 2: 
                        // a
                    case 1 when RandomObject.Next(1, 13) == 2:
                        // b
                        break;
                }
```

For some reason, in debug mode, the whole switch is being skipped completely. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I could possibly make it so it does work?

EDIT: Okay can someone tell me how to fix this instead because I remember coming up with something similar that does what I want to do and it did work but the problem is my hard drive crashed so I lost all of my data

Would this be possible?

```
switch(RandomObject)
{
   case 1 when RandomObject.Next(1,3) == 2:
   //do stuff
   break;
}
```

Comment: So it works in Release mode?

Comment: `Random.Next()` is going to return a random integer between 0 and 2147483647. You're then expecting that value to be 1 and *then* expecting one of the inner random conditions to also be true in order to hit the `break` statement. So it's not that it doesn't work, it's just extremely unlikely to happen.

Comment: Could you please explain what *you think* your code does? It'll help us help you.

Comment: @JohnG: It's called "pattern matching."  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions).

Comment: @Robert Harvey … Thank you for the info, I did not know this.

Comment: because the thing is I had an old piece of code that did what I want to do fine but my hard drive failed so I lost everything and I forgot what I did or what I should do

Comment: Based on what @devNull said, you probably want to shrink up the range on your `switch`, for example `switch (RandomObject.Next(1,5))`, that way you will have a 1 in 5 chance of either of your switch cases to hit.

Comment: @Andy - `RandomObject.Next(1,5)` gives a 1 in 4 chance of the number being 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will run tests to try to show you what's going wrong. Let's take this code, which is similar to your own:

```
int acount = 0, bcount = 0;
var r = new Random();

for(var i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; ++i) // 1 billion iterations
{
    switch (r.Next())
    {
        case 1 when r.Next(1, 3) == 2:
            ++acount;
            break;
        case 1 when r.Next(1, 13) == 2:
            ++bcount;
            break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"a case hit {acount} times");
Console.WriteLine($"b case hit {bcount} times");
```

The output is:

```
a case hit 0 times
b case hit 0 times
```

Now, let's try shrinking up your range on your switch statement:

```
// ...
switch (r.Next(1, 20))
{
// ...
```

Your results are now:

```
a case hit 26313397 times
b case hit 2191910 times
```

So what we are trying to tell you in the comments is `Random.Next()` returns a value in the range of `[0, 2147483647]`, which is near unlikely to ever return the value of 1, which is what your switch cases require to continue. By changing your range with much more reasonable values, your chances increase dramatically and is more than likely what you want.